# Get wrong date from material datepicker

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular-material, datepicker, nswag

I'm using
angular material 13 and
asp.net core 5 and use
nswag to generate client type script class.
also i customize dateadapter for angular material datepicker.

I have problem with sending date value to api because when I select a date for example "Feb 20 2022" I see the correct date in the field in chrome console but, when I call api and send the object to api i get the day before the date I have selected:

[client code]

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.frmCreateOvertimeSetting = this._formBuilder.group({
      effectiveDate: [null, Validators.required],
      description: [null],
    });
  }

  addOvertimeSetting() {
    let obj: CreateOvertimeSettingDTO = new CreateOvertimeSettingDTO();
    obj.effectiveDate = this.frmCreateOvertimeSetting.value.effectiveDate;
    obj.description = this.frmCreateOvertimeSetting.value.description;

    this.overtimeSettingIsProcessing = true;

    this._overtimeSettingService.create(obj).subscribe({
      next: (overtimeSettingId) => {

      },
    });
  }
```

[api code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BATV.png)

this is my adapter

```js
import {DateAdapter} from "@angular/material/core";
import * as jalaliMoment from 'jalali-moment'; /*  npm i jalali-moment */

export const PERSIAN_DATE_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'jYYYY/jMM/jDD'
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'jYYYY/jMM/jDD',
    monthYearLabel: 'jYYYY jMMMM',
    dateA11yLabel: 'jYYYY/jMM/jDD',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'jYYYY jMMMM'
  }
};

export class CustomDateAdapter extends DateAdapter<jalaliMoment.Moment> {

  constructor() {
    super();
    super.setLocale('fa');
  }

  getYear(date: jalaliMoment.Moment): number {
    return this.clone(date).jYear();
  }

  getMonth(date: jalaliMoment.Moment): number {
    return this.clone(date).jMonth();
  }

  getDate(date: jalaliMoment.Moment): number {
    return this.clone(date).jDate();
  }

  getDayOfWeek(date: jalaliMoment.Moment): number {
    return this.clone(date).day();
  }

  getMonthNames(style: 'long' | 'short' | 'narrow'): string[] {
    switch (style) {
      case 'long':
      case 'short':
        return jalaliMoment.localeData('fa').jMonths().slice(0);
      case 'narrow':
        return jalaliMoment.localeData('fa').jMonthsShort().slice(0);
    }
  }

  getDateNames(): string[] {
    const valuesArray = Array(31);
    for (let i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
      valuesArray[i] = String(i + 1);
    }
    return valuesArray;
  }

  getDayOfWeekNames(style: 'long' | 'short' | 'narrow'): string[] {
    switch (style) {
      case 'long':
        return jalaliMoment.localeData('fa').weekdays().slice(0);
      case 'short':
        return jalaliMoment.localeData('fa').weekdaysShort().slice(0);
      case 'narrow':
        return ['ی', 'د', 'س', 'چ', 'پ', 'ج', 'ش'];
    }
  }

  getYearName(date: jalaliMoment.Moment): string {
    return this.clone(date).jYear().toString();
  }

  getFirstDayOfWeek(): number {
    return jalaliMoment.localeData('fa').firstDayOfWeek();
  }

  getNumDaysInMonth(date: jalaliMoment.Moment): number {
    return this.clone(date).jDaysInMonth();
  }

  clone(date: jalaliMoment.Moment): jalaliMoment.Moment {
    return date.clone().locale('fa');
  }

  createDate(year: number, month: number, date: number): jalaliMoment.Moment {
    if (month < 0 || month > 11) {
      throw Error(
        `Invalid month index "${month}". Month index has to be between 0 and 11.`
      );
    }
    if (date < 1) {
      throw Error(`Invalid date "${date}". Date has to be greater than 0.`);
    }
    const result = jalaliMoment()
      .jYear(year).jMonth(month).jDate(date)
      .hours(0).minutes(0).seconds(0).milliseconds(0)
      .locale('fa');

    if (this.getMonth(result) !== month) {
      throw Error(`Invalid date ${date} for month with index ${month}.`);
    }
    if (!result.isValid()) {
      throw Error(`Invalid date "${date}" for month with index "${month}".`);
    }
    return result;
  }

  today(): jalaliMoment.Moment {
    return jalaliMoment().locale('fa');
  }

  parse(value: any, parseFormat: string | string[]): jalaliMoment.Moment | null {
    if (value && typeof value === 'string') {
      return jalaliMoment(value, parseFormat, 'fa');
    }
    return value ? jalaliMoment(value).locale('fa') : null;
  }

  format(date: jalaliMoment.Moment, displayFormat: string): string {
    date = this.clone(date);
    if (!this.isValid(date)) {
      throw Error('JalaliMomentDateAdapter: Cannot format invalid date.');
    }
    return date.format(displayFormat);
  }

  addCalendarYears(date: jalaliMoment.Moment, years: number): jalaliMoment.Moment {
    return this.clone(date).add(years, 'jYear');
  }

  addCalendarMonths(date: jalaliMoment.Moment, months: number): jalaliMoment.Moment {
    return this.clone(date).add(months, 'jmonth');
  }

  addCalendarDays(date: jalaliMoment.Moment, days: number): jalaliMoment.Moment {
    return this.clone(date).add(days, 'jDay');
  }

  toIso8601(date: jalaliMoment.Moment): string {
    return this.clone(date).format();
  }

  isDateInstance(obj: any): boolean {
    return jalaliMoment.isMoment(obj);
  }

  isValid(date: jalaliMoment.Moment): boolean {
    return this.clone(date).isValid();
  }

  invalid(): jalaliMoment.Moment {
    return jalaliMoment.invalid();
  }

  override deserialize(value: any): jalaliMoment.Moment | null {
    let date;
    if (value instanceof Date) {
      date = jalaliMoment(value);
    }
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
      if (!value) {
        return null;
      }
      date = jalaliMoment(value).locale('fa');
    }
    if (date && this.isValid(date)) {
      return date;
    }
    return super.deserialize(value);
  }
}
```

and this is my module

```js
providers: [
    
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: CustomDateAdapter },
    { provide: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, useValue: { useUtc: true } },
    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: PERSIAN_DATE_FORMATS}
  ],
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: convert to exact format by using moment

Comment: thanks , do you mean in adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Look, I know it's a weird cause, but I faced something similar before and I think your issue is related to the **timezone** converting.

let me explain that:

If we wanna create a new `Date` of `string` value without a `time`, we'll get this:

```
new Date("2022-03-14")
// the result is: Mon Mar 14 2022 03:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)
```

Try now to convert it to `toISOString`:

```
new Date('2022-03-14').toISOString()
// the result: '2022-03-14T00:00:00.000Z'
```

if you noticed, the time before converting it to was 3, and after converting it `ISOString` becomes 0 (12 AM).

Same way, if you create a new `Date` with no hours or (12 AM), like:

```
new Date('2022-03-14 00:00')
// the result: Mon Mar 14 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)
```

the result will be one day before, because it was (12 AM), converting to **GMT** (3 hrs before) it will be the previous day, like:

```
new Date('2022-03-14 00:00').toISOString()
// the result: '2022-03-13T21:00:00.000Z' -- one day before!!
```

What I'm trying to say, is you need to debug and log your date as `ISOString` to make sure it's not related to the `timezone` issue.